# How to set VisualSVN permission based on directories name?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I need to set VisualSVN permissions based on directories name. For example, if I have the following directories tree:

- Class_1

  - Src
  - Data types
- Class_2

  - Src
  - Data types

I want set every "Data types" directory in Read-only mode and everything else in No-Access mode.
I need an automatic rule, i can't set every single directory permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that wildcard permissions will help you, but they will become available in future product versions. Now, you can use the [VisualSVN Server PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) to automate permission management.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have an estimate about future product release?

Comment: @vent1 I cannot give you an ETA now.